# turn ... of a R function into a string

Tags: r, dplyr

In R, I want to write a function that takes in set of arguments, but doesn't evaluate them and returns the entire set of arguments as a string. I have found the following way to do this:

```
ff = function(...) {
  dots = dplyr::enquos(...)
  strs = sub("^[~]","=",sapply(dots,deparse))
  return(paste(paste(names(strs),strs,sep=""),collapse=","))
}
```

but it seems like there must be an easier, less fragile way to do this that does not depend on `dplyr` using the base R functions `quote` and `deparse`, but I can't figure it out.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Incidentally, your code doesn’t need to use dplyr, the `enquos` function is from rlang; dplyr just reexports it. And instead of `deparse` you could use `rlang::quo_text` to get the quosure text without the leading `~` (which, by the way, does not need to be escaped in a regular expression).

Comment: How do you call this `ff` function ? Can you show some sample input and expected output?

Comment: Thanks Konrad for your insightful comments. Regarding how I call it, typically something like ff(eval=!file.exists("blah"),connection="con"), but I wanted to keep the possibility of doing something like ff(mychunk,eval=!file.exists("blah")), which is why I asked Konrad the question about unnamed arguments below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match.call()`:

```
ff = function (...) {
    args = match.call()[-1L]
    argvalues = vapply(args, deparse, character(1L))
    paste(names(args), argvalues, sep = ' = ', collapse = ', ')
}
```

Or, if you *only* want the dots, and not potential positional arguments, change just the first line of that function to

```
args = match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
```

Comment: I am not sure I totally understand it all, but this is a great help. Thanks for the quick reply. One thing: if I do ff(a=1,zzz), it returns "a=1,=zzz". Is there a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Konrad's solution above, here is the final function that I am using:

```
ff = function (...) {
  args = match.call(expand.dots=FALSE)$...
  argvalues = vapply(args, deparse, character(1L))
  paste(ifelse(names(args)=="",argvalues,
               paste(names(args), argvalues, sep = ' = ')),
        collapse = ', ')
}
```

Using this, I can do the following:

```
> ff(a=1,b=zzz)
[1] "a = 1, b = zzz"
> ff(a=1,zzz)
[1] "a = 1, zzz"
```